# How to map cube uvs from existing tilesheet?

Tags: uv

I have a tilesheet with 128x128px tiles with 2px offsets. When I unwrap a cube to map faces to the tilesheet, I can't figure out how to accurately scale the face uvs so that they are exactly 128px. I'm currently trying to eye it, but my uvs end up being imprecise.

Is there a correct way to unwrap cube faces to a tilesheet?

Thanks!

[image: Tilesheet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable *Snap to Pixels* in *UV editor > Header > UVs* to snap UVs exactly.

1. Use the *Reset* unwrap method (<kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>) to unwrap all the faces of the cube over the whole UV space.
2. Scale (<kbd>S</kbd>) the resulting UV faces down to the area you want.
3. Select faces on the cube and reposition/rotate their corresponding UV face accordingly.

[image]